# Put div inside background div

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my website, I'm making a menu, I'm trying to put the hamburger icon inside another div, to get a black background for it, but all I get is [this.](http://prntscr.com/e2v721) I also, want the hamburger and background to sit on the left side. Does anyone knwo how to do this?

```js
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

// based on Todd Motto functions
// http://toddmotto.com/labs/reusable-js/

// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
  }
  // addClass

function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
      elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
  }
  // removeClass

function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
      while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
        newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
      }
      elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
  }
  // toggleClass

function toggleClass(elem, className) {
  var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, " ") + ' ';
  if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
    while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0) {
      newClass = newClass.replace(" " + className + " ", " ");
    }
    elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  } else {
    elem.className += ' ' + className;
  }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
  toggleClass(this, 'on');
  return false;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
video.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div.vid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}
footer {
  background: #222020;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 99%;
}
p.copyright {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
div.footer {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
div.menuback {
  background-color: #222020;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
/* Important styles */

#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}
#toggle span:after {
  top: 9px;
}
#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* on activation */

#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
#toggle.on + #menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
/* menu appearance*/

#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
ul,
li,
li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}
li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}
/* demo styles */

body {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background: #eee;
  color: #555;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
p,
p a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>
  <div class="menuback">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<div class="vid">
  <video class="home" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
    <source src="Images/TransitionName.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <p>Video not supported</p>
  </video>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2017 WILLIAM CHEN</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added anchor tag in wrong place

```js
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

// based on Todd Motto functions
// http://toddmotto.com/labs/reusable-js/

// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
  }
  // addClass

function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
      elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
  }
  // removeClass

function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
      while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
        newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
      }
      elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
  }
  // toggleClass

function toggleClass(elem, className) {
  var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, " ") + ' ';
  if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
    while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0) {
      newClass = newClass.replace(" " + className + " ", " ");
    }
    elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  } else {
    elem.className += ' ' + className;
  }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
  toggleClass(this, 'on');
  return false;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
video.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div.vid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}
footer {
  background: #222020;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 99%;
}
p.copyright {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
div.footer {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
div.menuback {
  background-color: #222020;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
/* Important styles */

#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}
#toggle span:after {
  top: 9px;
}
#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* on activation */

#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
#toggle.on + #menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
/* menu appearance*/

#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
ul,
li,
li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}
li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}
/* demo styles */

body {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background: #eee;
  color: #555;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
p,
p a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Awesome Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="menuback">
    <!--- menu toggle added here --->
    <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<div class="vid">
  <video class="home" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
    <source src="Images/TransitionName.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <p>Video not supported</p>
  </video>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2017 WILLIAM CHEN</p>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```